# WebService: edit objects before send them to the client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, asmx

I'm developing an application that uses webservices to search data, insert records in database, etc.

I have a problem: I have some string properties in objects that are filled with spaces at the end, or with just spaces. This is really annoying :/

I had an idea: trim all string properties on the webservice before send the objects to the client. This would solve my problem :D

Is this possible using reflection or some other thing?

```
//WebMethod
public MillenniumCoreCustomer LoadCustomer()
{
     MyObject returnObj = new MyObject();
     returnObj = GetDataFromSourceNotControlatedByMe();

     // I want to trim all string properties here
     return returnObj;
}
```

Comment: Do you have the ability to modify the webservice code?

Comment: I know it's out of the question scope but you don't have to `new MyObject()` to dismiss the reference on the next line ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can, but it's a terrible idea.

Imagine you send 10,000 objects. You'll be using reflection on those 10,000 rows just to trim string properties. Worse, you'll have "to search" the property list of each object until you find the ones that are strings.

Just call `Trim()` on the string properties. You already know which ones they are.

**EDIT**
On your code you already have a reference to MyObject which already exposes which properties are strings and which aren't. Just call Trim() on those properties but since strings are immutable, make sure you do something like

```
myObject.StringProperty=myObject.StringProperty.Trim();
```

Comment: Yes, I understand all that problems, just tell me how can I do that?

Comment: Post the web service call and where in your code you want to trim your strings

Answer (score 0):

This is a very bad idea.

Your service is meant to query the database and return data. That's what it should do.

If you don't want trailing spaces, then don't put the trailing spaces into the database to begin with.

Comment: I can not agree more with you but i am on outsourcing and my problem is: my webservice is consuming other webservices from the client. That webservices are completely crazy :/ Some properties come with spaces at the end, or only spaces. This is where my problem appears, I need something that remove automaticly that spaces. This is why I thought to Trim at my webservice.

Comment: P. S.: It is impossible to tell to the client to change them webservices... they are immaculate. Lol